# Conversion of unmanaged type structure pointer into managed type structure pointer

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli

Consider the following stucture in c++, I need to wrap this using CLI to make it usable for C#

```
typedef struct A
{
    int b[5];
    A* next;
};
```

How can I do so? Please help.

*non-op edit:*

What I've tried is the following:

```
  public ref struct ANET 
    {
        array<int>^ b;
        ANET^ next;         
        ANET()
        { b = gcnew array<int>(5) } 
    };
```

now let's say we have an pointer of object of A is a, pointer of object ofANET is aNET

```
nSize = sizeof(a->b)/sizeof(a->b[0]);
Marshal::Copy( IntPtr( ( void * ) a->b ), aNET->b, 0, nSize);
```

so far I am able get the values of a->b in aNET->b but I am stuck with marshaling the pointer of a->next to aNET->next.

Thanks

Comment: yes, I tried as follows,
public ref struct ANET
{
array<int>^ b;
ANET^ next;
ANET()
{
b= gcnew array<int>(5);
//didn't get the solution for converting A* into ANET^. 
}
};

Answer (score 1):

That's a linked list. So one option is to write C++/CLI code to adapt the native linked list to a .net [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx). Going down this route will mean that you need to make copies of the list whenever it is modified in the native code and needs to be returned to the managed code. And vice versa.

If making copies is not an option then you should wrap the native linked list in a managed class. So you don't try to convert the struct definition at all. Instead you write a C++/CLI managed class that encapsulates the functionality that you need to expose. I can't say much more than that because you haven't given any information on the operations that you need to perform on this list. Now have you explained what the data flow is.

Comment: Not sure this is a good solution.  `LinkedList` doesn't provide any hooks for modification of the list, so keeping the native data structure in sync with a .NET `LinkedList` won't be possible -- the native list would have to be rebuilt from scratch frequently, and for some native APIs providing an entirely new list might not have the desired behavior.

Comment: @David : I guess he wants to say that LinkedList does not notify when it is modified via a CollectionChanged event or similar which would make synchronizing with another collection more complex.